# Auto completion in JetBrains consoles

Tags: console, window, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm and PhpStorm and I have the same problem for both:
I don't have auto-completion using the console.

[image: Example]

For example here I have a folder with a name starting with `rn` and when I want to auto-complete with tab it make a tab :/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I decided to use an another shell : bash

in Tool > Terminal > shell path